# Do all functions in $L^2$ have a power series representations that converges everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, hilbert-spaces

The Hermite Gaussians defined by
\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x)=e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)
\end{equation}
where $H_n$ are the Hermite polynomials, span the space of real $L^2$ functions, and one can show that the Gaussian function $e^{-x^2}$ has a Taylor series which converges for all $x$ via the ratio test
\begin{equation}
r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg\vert\frac{c_{n-1}}{c_n}\bigg\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2x^2}=\infty
\end{equation}
where $c_n$ is the $n$th term in the Taylor series expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ about $x=0$. Does that mean that given any function $f(x)$ in $L^2$ I can first write it as a sum of Hermite Gaussians, and then write those Hermite Gaussians as infinite sums to get a power series representation of $f(x)$ which converges for all $x$?

If this is correct, then how come the $L^2$ function
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\frac 1{1+x^2}
\end{equation}
has a Taylor series about $x=0$ which only converges between $x=-1$ and $x=1$? By writing $g(x)$ as a sum over Hermite Gaussians and then writing those as Taylor series shouldn't I be able to obtain a power series for $g(x)$ which converges for all $x$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, not even close. What you can say is there is a linear combination of these $\psi_n$'s that is $L^2$ close (close in mean, not even a pointwise *almost everywhere* statement, and not even implying a pointwise convergence result). You can also just look at the standard example to see that smooth functions need not have power series convergent everywhere: $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2),x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You can say this about all functions that are finite linear combinations of $\psi_n$'s, but that leaves a lot out of $L^2$ and isn't close to complete.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks for the reply. So is it correct to say that my reasoning is correct so long as I’m talking about functions in $L^2$ which are finite sums of $\psi_n$s? But that for an infinite sum of $\psi_n$s just because each one has an everywhere convergent power series does not mean that the whole has an everywhere convergent power series?

Comment: Finite sums are very restrictive. For infinite sums, consider a case where $\psi_n = x^n$. Each $\psi$ has an everywhere convergent power series but the infinite sum sum $\sum x^n$ only converges when $|x|<1$.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you. That’s a very illuminating example.